# No member named 'name' in namespace 'namespace'

Tags: c++, namespaces

I can't for the life of me figure out why this error is being generated as I'm pretty sure the syntax is correct (obviously I'm wrong!). So I figured I'd see if anyone here could point it out for me.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Object.h"

int main(){
    out = json::readJSON(data_dir + "a2-empty_array_with_empty_object.json", e, debug);
}
```

**Object.h**

```
namespace json{
template<typename T>
    std::string readJSON(std::string jsonFile, T& object, bool debug = false, char delimiter = ',') {}
}
```

I'm basically getting this error, when clearly the function is in the namespace. Why does it refer to the function as a member? Maybe there is something else going on here...

Error:

```
a2main.cpp:66:21: error: no member named 'readJSON' in namespace 'json'
        out = json::readJSON(data_dir + "a2-cartoons.json", c, debug, '|');
```

Comment: Make sure you are `#include`ing the appropriate files.

Comment: I am, I've double and triple checked.

Comment: Have you tried qualifying the template e.g readJson<YourType>? My first hunch is a template issue.

Comment: The 'data_dir', 'e' and 'debug' names are nowhere declared in posted code.

Comment: None of the above solutions seemed to have solved it. As for the undeclared variables, I didn't post them because they seem rather irrelevant to the problem. The struggle with learning C++!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably not including the header files correctly.

The following code compiles (with both clang and gcc) and runs fine

```
#include <string>

namespace json
{

    template<typename T>
    std::string readJSON(std::string jsonFile, T& object, bool debug = false, char delimiter = ',') 
    {
       return "Hello"; //This function should return a string
    }

}

int main()
{
    std::string data_dir = "test-";
    int e = 3;
    bool debug = false;
    std::string out = json::readJSON(data_dir + "a2-empty_array_with_empty_object.json", e, debug);
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

#include

//that will fix the error %100